# Android changing AlertDialog text on each click

Tags: android, alert

I have a list of messages I would liek to displkay to the user. These are stored in an array. I'd then like to show an alert and on the user clicks the positive button, go through the messages one by one.

_msgCount is a private variable in my class.

msgs is a local final variable.

All of my logging happens. But the message never changes. I have tried also doing _alert.hide() then setMessage() and then _alert.show().

Thanks for any help!

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        _alert = builder.setTitle("Whoa there!")
               .setMessage(msgs[_msgCount])
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                    {
                        Log.i("EasterHunt", "On positive click");
                        _alert.setMessage(msgs[++_msgCount]);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                    {
                        Log.i("EasterHunt", "On negative click");
                        Toast.makeText(MapsMarkerActivity.this, R.string.nope, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .create();



        _alert.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
            {
                Log.i("EasterHunt", "what!");
            }
        });
```

Comment: have you tried something like this : dialogInterface.setMessage(msgs[++_msgCount]);

Comment: More like this (AlertDialog)dialogInterface.setMessage(msgs[++_msgCount]);  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need override the positive button click to disable dialog's dismiss action. Do something like this

```
...
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        // leave this empty
    }
})
...;

_alert.show(); // show the dialog before getting its button

_alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.i("EasterHunt", "On positive click");
        if (_msgCount < msgs.length - 1) {
            _alert.setMessage(msgs[++_msgCount]);    
        } else {
            // do some action
            _alert.dismiss();
        }

    }
})
```

Comment: Nice. One point to mention: before performing `getButton()` the dialog should already been shown, i.e.: `_alert.show()` should have been performed.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that. I'll add that to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is what I actually ended up doing before I got your answer, but thank you for the response and the code! Also as for it being shown first.... I ran into that lol!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you can change a message of an already built AlertDialog.
try to create a new one each time.

```
 String[] msgs = new String[] { "ciao", "boh", "buh" };
  int _msgCount = 0;

  private void showDialog() {
    if (_msgCount >= msgs.length) return;

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Whoa there!")
        .setMessage(msgs[_msgCount++])
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Log.i("EasterHunt", "On positive click");
            showDialog();
          }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Log.i("EasterHunt", "On negative click");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nope", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        })
        .show();
  }
```